# Android - MockitoJUnitRunner - Cursor getCount always returns 0

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to use a cursor in my unit test with Mockito but getCount() method always return 0 even if I add a row. Someone can help me?

```
final Cursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"ID", "name", "data"});
((MatrixCursor) cursor).addRow(new Object[]{1, "myName", "myData"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "standard" Mockito mock feature allows to record a behavior for a mock object.
What you write looks like a Mockito spy (you mock a part of the object under test) and should be used only in legacy context (as you don't have choice).

In your case, suppose you write an unit test for a `boolean foo()` method of a `MyClassToTest` class that relies on a Cursor object and which you wish mock the  `getCount()` invocation to test the possible use cases.

Suppose that as you have two cases to test :

- case where `foo()` returns `true` as `Cursor.getCount()` return 0
- case where `foo()` returns `false` as `Cursor.getCount()` return 1 or more.

You could write something as :

```
@Mock
Cursor cursor;

@Test
public void add_return_true_if_no_element(){
      Mock.when(cursor.getCount()).thenReturn(0);
      Assert.assertTrue(new MyClassToTest().foo(cursor))
}

@Test
public void add_return_false_if_at_least_one_element(){
      Mock.when(cursor.getCount()).thenReturn(1);
      Assert.assertFalse(new MyClassToTest().foo(cursor))
}
```